# @react-oauth/google with nextjs getting 'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')'

Tags: next.js, google-oauth

With Nextjs 13 I am unable to get google O-Auth to work. [Using this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google)

The code snippet from the documentation is

```js
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';

<GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="<your_client_id>">...</GoogleOAuthProvider>;
```

And I have no idea what to do with it

My attempt is the following:

```js
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';


export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (<GoogleOAuthProvider
    clientId="secret"
  >
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </GoogleOAuthProvider>)
}
```

But this will return me
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')`

The top of the call stack is

```
Call Stack
Object.useState
file:///C:/Users/mozol/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js (1622:21)
useLoadGsiScript
file:///C:/Users/mozol/node_modules/@react-oauth/google/dist/index.js (13:75)
GoogleOAuthProvider
file:///C:/Users/mozol/node_modules/@react-oauth/google/dist/index.js (43:38)
```

I have tried many different configurations all to no avaial and have no idea how to fix the error.

How is google O-Auth supposed to be used in nextjs 13?

Comment: I'm getting the same error with Next 13. Have you found a solution?