# React Google OAuth2

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

I have to implement Google OAuth2 in React.

This is code of my app:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import {GoogleOAuthProvider} from "@react-oauth/google";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <GoogleOAuthProvider
            clientId="456606812667-thitf7kr69bukm71bmecv5******.apps.googleusercontent.com">
                <App />
        </GoogleOAuthProvider>
    </Router>,

    document.getElementById('root'));
```

But I get this error:

```js
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48755:25)
    at useLoadGsiScript (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47023:114)
    at GoogleOAuthProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47060:36)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25305:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28591:17)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29887:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14897:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14941:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14998:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34872:11)
```

I'm very new to React and I haven't worked with Google OAuth so I have no idea how to solve it. Maybe wrong clientID but I don't know how to check it

Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Similar question without answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75623127/18085239)

Comment: Can you make an example of what you tried here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new, One think I can tell you right away is that you need to use the `GoogleLogin` component